# question on c++ reference

Tags: c++, object, vector, reference, variable-assignment

suppose I have this vector

```
vector<Object> m;
```

and then I have the following assignments:

```
vector<Object> o = m;
vector<Object> k = &m;
```

vector o will be a COPY of vector m whereas vector k will point to the exact same object as vector m....am I right?

in other words, if I go, `o.push_back(something)`, this will modify vector o but not vector m whereas if I go `k.push_back(something)`, this will indeed modify vector m.

am I wrong or right?

Comment: Try compiling the code before posting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right for `o`, wrong for `k`.

```
vector<Object> k = &m;
//                 ^^ -- you're taking the address of m here
```

To make a reference, use

```
vector<Object>& k = m;
//            ^ -- this makes a reference
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's conceptually right - except you missed an asterisk or perhaps used an ampersand too much in your sample.

```
vector<Object> o = m;
vector<Object>* k = &m; // use address-of (&) to create a pointer (*) to m
```

Pointers always carry this `*` with them.

Now, `m.push_back(...)` and `k->push_back(...)` modify exactly the same object. Note the use of `->`, which is used to access a member of a pointer.

If you want to create a reference, you don't use the `&` - think of it being done implicitly by the compiler:

```
vector<Object>& k = m; // no address-of here, but k is a reference to m
```

now, `k.push_back()` can be used to access `m`.

Comment: "Now, `o.push_back(...)` and `k->push_back(...)` modify exactly the same object." -- sorry, but this is wrong. `o` is a copy, so it's a distinct object. I think you meant `m` both times?

Comment: Jep, now it's correct. :) +1 for a more lengthy explanation. And whoever downvoted, please explain, it's corrected now.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it appears to me that the OP was asking about references, not pointers, so maybe that's why.

Comment: you're right - at a first glance it appeared to me as if he'd intended to create a pointer due to his use of `&`, and later realized that the outspoken intend must have been to create a reference. Still leaving the response here as it nonetheless answers the question and might be of use to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not even compile. The type of the expression `&m` is `vector<Object>*`, which cannot be assigned to the variable `k` (its type is `vector<Object>`).

Possibly you meant to do this:

```
vector<Object> o = m;
vector<Object>& k = m;
```

in which case `o` will be a copy of `m` (resulting in `o` and `m` having copies of the same elements, therefore modifying the contents of one will not affect the contents of the other) and both `m` and `k` will refer to the same instance (therefore any change on the instance using one of the two variables will be immediately visible when you refer to the vector using the other variable).